# How to format string in JSTL core tags?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am using JSP EL. I have a string like `"Village Green,Colgate University,Hamilton,NY"`. I want to show only `Village Green`. How can I do this?

```
<c:forEach items="${listOfSources}" var = "source">
    <option value="${source }" >${source }</option>
</c:forEach>
```

The option value should be the whole string, but I want to show only `Village Green` to select. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use just `substringBefore` from `JSTL` assuming that you need `String` from0 to first `,`

---

**Code Snippet:**

```
<c:out value="${fn:substringBefore(source,',')}"/>
```

---

**Document :**

- [`fn:substringBefore()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/substringBefore.fn.html)